# ProgressDialog equivalent for iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm starting development for iOS using Xamarin.iOS and I want know if is there a ProgressDialog of android equivalent in iOS?

In other words, I want create a modal like  this in iOS:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think,

https://components.xamarin.com/view/mbprogresshud/

Is the best option. You can find the information from here

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/mbprogresshud

**EDIT 1**

Here is a static class written by me. Hope will help you

```
using CoreGraphics;
using MBProgressHUD;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using UIKit;
namespace CandyCaneClub.iOS.Helper
{
/*
A generic helper class to show and hide the overlay for running processes on application 
*/
    public class OverlayHelper 
    {
        public static MTMBProgressHUD overlay;
        //Initialize the Overlay with string as a message to show and view on which we suppose to show
        public static MTMBProgressHUD InitOverlay(string message, UIView view)
        {
            overlay = new MTMBProgressHUD(view)
            {
                LabelText = message,
                RemoveFromSuperViewOnHide = true
            };
            overlay.Alpha = 0.75f;
            view.AddSubview(overlay);
            overlay.Show(animated: true);
            return overlay;
        }
        //Hide the overlay 
        public static void HideOverlay()
        {
            if(overlay != null)
            overlay.Hide(animated: true, delay: 2);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated an answer with Example

Answer (score 1):

Xamarin has a complete recipe posted for this exact view.
 https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message/

```
public class LoadingOverlay : UIView {

    // control declarations
    UIActivityIndicatorView activitySpinner;
    UILabel loadingLabel;

    public LoadingOverlay (CGRect frame) : base (frame)
    {
        // configurable bits
        BackgroundColor = UIColor.Black;
        Alpha = 0.75f;
        AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;

        nfloat labelHeight = 22;
        nfloat labelWidth = Frame.Width - 20;

        // derive the center x and y
        nfloat centerX = Frame.Width / 2;
        nfloat centerY = Frame.Height / 2;

        // create the activity spinner, center it horizontall and put it 5 points above center x
        activitySpinner = new UIActivityIndicatorView(UIActivityIndicatorViewStyle.WhiteLarge);
        activitySpinner.Frame = new CGRect (
            centerX - (activitySpinner.Frame.Width / 2) ,
            centerY - activitySpinner.Frame.Height - 20 ,
            activitySpinner.Frame.Width,
            activitySpinner.Frame.Height);
        activitySpinner.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
        AddSubview (activitySpinner);
        activitySpinner.StartAnimating ();

        // create and configure the "Loading Data" label
        loadingLabel = new UILabel(new CGRect (
            centerX - (labelWidth / 2),
            centerY + 20 ,
            labelWidth ,
            labelHeight
            ));
        loadingLabel.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
        loadingLabel.TextColor = UIColor.White;
        loadingLabel.Text = "Loading Data...";
        loadingLabel.TextAlignment = UITextAlignment.Center;
        loadingLabel.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.All;
        AddSubview (loadingLabel);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Fades out the control and then removes it from the super view
    /// </summary>
    public void Hide ()
    {
        UIView.Animate (
            0.5, // duration
            () => { Alpha = 0; },
            () => { RemoveFromSuperview(); }
        );
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[This Xamarin.IOS documentation link](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/ios/standard_controls/popovers/display_a_loading_message/) should give you what you need to build a progress dialog. In their example, the progress dialog is taking the whole screen, but tweaking with some of the parameters, you can make it basically look what you want it to.